# Kenda cyclo cross 27 x 1 3/8 fit on 27 x 1 1/4 rim?

Tags: tire

Will the kenda K161 cyclocross tires (27x1 3/8s) fit on a 27x1 1/4 rim?

I havent been successful at finding this question on here or on google, apologies if it has been asked a million times.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd have thought you'll be fine with the tyre fitting the rim, there's usually some leeway there, but also make sure about brake clearance.

Comment: Back when I was running 27" tires it was common to swap tire widths, within reason, and I don't recall anyone ever having problems.  According to [Sheldon](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html), all 27" tires should be 630 rims.

Comment: I have done it .. It seems to work. The bike shop warned me that putting a 1-3/8 tire on a 1-1/4 rim could cause the the bicycle to topple ..

Comment: Hi @Austin, does the tire fit? I want to buy  a pair of Kenda K161 for my 27 1 1/4 rims because the roads get slippery during the winter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can confirm tyre fit using the ETRTO spec, which should be specified on the sidewalls of your Kendas and the tyres that were previously fitted.

the format is

```
ww-ddd
```

where `ww` is the nominal tyre width (often measured at the widest point when fitted to the manufacturer's test rim, rather than at the tread) in millimetres, and `ddd` is the bead diameter in .

I would expect a 27 x 1 1/4" tyre to be specified **28-630**.

[According to Sheldon](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html), there is no other standard bead diameter using *27"* as its nominal measurement, so any "27" tyre is likely to have a 630mm bead. 1 3/8" is equivalent to 35mm.

I have not previously encountered any cyclists using 27" wheels for cyclocross. I assumed "700c"/622mm to be panacea for all but the shortest of CX competitors.

Comment: These are commuter-cross tires, which is probably why they're still available for 27" rims (for the commuter part).

Comment: Ah, seems the Cyclocross angle was indeed a red herring; Austin previously asked a question about a Sekai 2000 in which he mentioned its 28-630 tyres.

Comment: Also 27" is slightly bigger than 700c - a smaller rider would likely want 650b.

Comment: I haven't seen a 650B CX bike yet; the non-700c riders I hinted at would be more likely using 650c or 26" (559mm) depending on their background.